# Way to redirect all Product Sub Category to its Main category Page?

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

How to redirect all Product Sub Categories to its Main category Page respectively.

This is a question to find a way.

Comment: Or you could move all your products into top level categories only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use JS for the redirection since header is already sent before we can check the category, following snippet would do the work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','redirect_to_top_level_parent',1);
function redirect_to_top_level_parent(){
    if (is_product_category()){
        $cate = get_queried_object(); $cateID = $cate->term_id;
        $parentcats = get_ancestors($cateID, 'product_cat');
        $count = count($parentcats);
        if ($count > 0){
            $count = $count-1;
            $link = get_term_link( $parentcats[$count], 'product_cat' );
            $redirect = "<script>";
            $redirect .= "window.location.replace('{$link}');";
            $redirect .= "</script>";
            echo $redirect;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great it Worked!